# How to convert the string of a byte array to a byte array

Tags: c, arduino

This may seem a little stupid but I'm writing data on my RFID cards and I write in these kinds of forms :

```
{0x31,0x32,0x33,0x39}
```

And I currently have that in a string

```
"0x31,0x32,0x33,0x39"
```

Is there any way to pass from the string to the byte array ?
**Thank you in advance !**

Here's the code I have so far but really don't know how to make it work Sorry I'm new but Steve Summit do I need to use all of them in a specific order ?

```
String str = "0x31,0x32,0x33,0x39";
byte Myarray[18];
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
int i = 0;
void loop() {
  for (i; i<str.length();++i) {
  Myarray[i] = strtol(str, 0, 16);
  }
Serial.println(Myarray);
}
```

Comment: You can loop through the string, using combinations of functions such as `strtok`, `sscanf`, and/or `strtol`, to convert each string-representation-of-a-hex-byte to an actual byte.

Comment: `array[i] = strtol(str, 0, 16)` and place it in a loop.

Comment: Tesseract_, does the target array have a max size?

Comment: Reinstate Monica in this situation I store up to 18 hex numbers

Comment: if you store 18 hex numbers why is `Myarray` only 16 bytes long?

Comment: Oh thank you but I still get : cannot convert string to const charfor argument 1 for strtol

Comment: `byte Myarray[16]` is declaring a 16 element array (you said you want 18 hex numbers). `Myarray[i] = strtol(str, 0, 18);` is trying to use base (18??) to decode an hex? hex is base 16.

Comment: Ok, now your for loop doesn't initialize `i` (`i` is declared outside the loop function so it's a global variable). The for loop will only work once and then `i` will never meet the conditions for the for loop again.

Comment: It's just a test, yes it will work once but I will look at the functions that Steve Summit indicated

Comment: the values are read from where? are those hard-coded?

Comment: The string is a result of a bit of code that I made

Comment: If you control the way the string is constructed, it's in your power to select something that's easier to parse and convert on the other end!

Comment: It's what I'm trying to do thank you!

Comment: `strtol` will parse it for you, you just need to provide an endpointer so it can parse more than one number https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: The only problem I have is I'd be getting {"0x31","0x32","0x33","0x39"} instead of {0x31,0x32,0x33,0x39}

Comment: How do I go from "0x31" to the byte 0x31

Comment: If that's where you are, you could use `n = sscanf(str, "0x%x", &bytevar)`.  After that, if `n` is 1, `bytevar` should contain `0x31`.  Or `strtol(str, NULL, 16)` would work, too, I guess.  Or `n = sscanf(str, "%i", &bytevar)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x31 = 49 so
I can write it under this form:

```
{49,50,51,57}
```

which is much easier to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C function [strtok](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to tokenize the string. You can use [strtol](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to convert a string to number.

```
  char data[] = "0x31,0x32,0x33,0x39";
  byte arr[4];
  int length = 0;
  const char* delim = ",";
  char* tok = strtok(data, delim);
  while (tok && length < sizeof(arr)) {
    arr[length++] = strtol(tok, NULL, 16);
    tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print(arr[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
```

Note: strtok will change `data`. It will replace the delimiter `,` with string termination character.

Comment: What I want to do is that it returns a bytearray like that : {0x31,0x32,0x33,0x39}
Is that what it does and I tried multiple variables in this bit of code but it doesn't work :/

Comment: it is the `arr` array

Comment: Yeah without these -> ""
Basically a byte array of my comment
I tried arr but it didn't gave me the same result as the expected

Comment: `arr` is at the end same as `byte arr[] = {0x31,0x32,0x33,0x39};`

Comment: I think I know the issue, it actually is byte arr[] = {31,32,33,39}
And not byte arr[] = {0x31,0x32,0x33,0x39}
And what I use to write on my cards only take this format

Comment: 31 is a different value than 0x31. 0x31 is 49 in decimal

Comment: Thank you so much Juraj it worked ! Look at the answer I left for more information